# Angular set model to null does not select empty option

Tags: angularjs

http://plnkr.co/edit/JVMZqnY5Vilek4NxDNGE?p=preview

There is a select like this (nothing unusual here):

```
 <select ng-model="model.selectedValue"
         ng-options="value.id as value.value for value in modelOptions">
 <option value="" ng-if="!model.selectedValue">Null</option>
```

Initially the model is null, so when the page first opens the Null option is selected.

```
$scope.model ={"selectedValue":null};
```

However, if I then change the selected value to something else, and then back to null by clicking these two buttons

```
<button ng-click="model.selectedValue=1">Select Yes</button>
<button ng-click="model.selectedValue=null">Select Null</button>
```

then the Null option is NOT selected - so now the UI is out of sync with the model.

Clearly this is a bug with Angular (1.2.22), but is there any workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got an answer from the Angular team at https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/8670.

This was actually working up to version 1.2.14 but they don't think it's a bug. Apparently the right thing to do is not use the *ng-if* inside the *select*, and instead work with the model,  the Javascript array of options the *select* is binding to.

I assume for the code sample in the question, this means setting up a watcher on *model.selectedValue* and adding/removing a Null option to/from *modelOptions* as appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

Change the `ng-if` to `ng-show`:

`<option value="" ng-show="!model.selectedValue">Null</option>`

This is because `ng-if` creates a new scope, so you could also use `ng-if` along side `$parent`:
 `<option value="" ng-if="!$parent.model.selectedValue">Null</option>`

Comment: Thanks, `ng-show` did fix the problem. What's strange is with `ng-if="!model.selectedValue"` the _ng-if_ itself works fine - it always removes and adds back the `option` as expected. It's the binding in the `select` that gets confused by the the `option` being removed and added back.

Comment: Actually, I spoke too soon - both `ng-show` and `$parent` fix the problem in Chrome, but in IE 10 they fix the binding problem but cause another one - now the Null option isn't removed anymore when I select Yes or No.